I wrote a content-type handler for Firefox, but the script can't access utilities under /usr
I wrote a script for processing .qfx files, and can call it from firefox when I download them.
The processing works the way I want, but the script also tries to call utilities under /usr.
This worked fine under Ubuntu 20.04, but with Ubuntu 24.04 it's not working. I added some checks to the script and see this, for example, in the error-log that my script generates:
process_QFX: line 37: /usr/bin/df: Permission denied

I'm guessing that when Firefox runs a script, it's in some funny ("safe"?) mode -- or user+group -- that doesn't have full access to the system. I'm invoking Firefox from the GNOME panel, should that cause this kind of problem?

The ps command indicates that all the firefox processes are running under my UID.

Note also that script can write files into /home/$USER but not /tmp.

are you using the default Firefox install that comes with Ubuntu? if so, I believe it runs under snap (at least the default Firefox did for Ubuntu 22.04);   fwiw ... a bit of web searching on firefox "permission denied" is bringing up issues with Firefox installed/running under snap in Ubuntu 22.04+; the general issue has to do with snap limiting (sandboxing) applications' access to only dirs/files under the user's home directory; gist of the (easier) resolutions: uninstall/remove snap/Firefox, install Firefox via apt install or a *.deb file ... to be continued ...

... this is bringing up memories of all sorts of issues with snap when setting up my first Ubuntu 22.04 instance (a couple years ago); had lots of problems with default apps (Firefox, VLC, etc) not wanting to work with an assortment of files installed in custom directories (other than my home dir); I ended up ripping out all of the snap-managed applications and replacing them with apt install or *.deb file equivalents

Ugh. Yeah, that makes sense. So this is all by design.... is there a way to re-configure snap to be more accomodating? There's some utility in keeping the integrated Ubuntu configuration....
For that matter, is there a name for this kind of behavior? It sounds like some kind of "safe" mode.

Digging around, I see enough explanation of the issue:
https://superuser.com/questions/1721697/how-do-i-allow-firefox-as-a-snap-to-run-an-external-program and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323771/snap-strict-applications-under-ubuntu-20-04-cant-access-mounted-folders-under for example.
